# How do I get the number of items per page to work in pagination

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using Laravel-vue-pagination with renderless pagination (laravel-vue-pagination.org) in my Laravel Nova custom tool. I have the pagination working at the standard 10 items per page but I want to be able to change the itemsPerPage drop-down and have this set the number of items per page.

Here is my manager components code:

```
    <div>
        <Heading :level="1" class="mb-3 flex items-center">
            <span>Adverts</span>
        </Heading>

        <div class="flex mb-6">
            <IndexSearchInput
                :placeholder="searchPlaceholder"
            />
            <div class="w-full flex items-center" >
                <!-- Create / Attach Button -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <Card>
            <div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row md:items-center py-3 border-b border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700">
                <div class="flex items-center flex-1">
                    <div class="md:ml-3">
                        <SelectAllDropdown
                            v-if="shouldShowCheckBoxes"
                            :all-matching-resource-count="allMatchingResourceCount"
                            :current-page-count="currentPageCount"
                            @toggle-select-all="toggleSelectAll"
                            @toggle-select-all-matching="toggleSelectAllMatching"
                            @deselect="$emit('deselect')"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex items-center pr-2 md:pr-3">
                        <!-- ...existing code... -->
                        <div class="h-9 ml-auto flex items-center">
                            <div class="hidden md:flex px-2">
                                <label for="itemsPerPage" class="sr-only">Items Per Page</label>
                                <select
                                    id="itemsPerPage"
                                    class="rounded-md border-gray-300 dark:border-gray-600 focus:border-primary-500 focus:ring focus:ring-primary-200 dark:focus:ring-gray-600"
                                    v-model="itemsPerPage"
                                    @change="onItemsPerPageChange"
                                >
                                    <option value="10">10 per page</option>
                                    <option value="20">20 per page</option>
                                    <option value="50">50 per page</option>
                                    <option value="100">100 per page</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
<!--                    <div class="h-9 ml-auto flex items-center pr-2 md:pr-3"><div class="hidden md:flex px-2">&lt;!&ndash;&ndash;&gt;</div>&lt;!&ndash;&ndash;&gt;&lt;!&ndash;&ndash;&gt;<div class="flex h-9 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 rounded" dusk="filter-selector"><button aria-expanded="false" class="rounded active:outline-none active:ring focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-primary-200 dark:focus:ring-gray-600" type="button"><span class="sr-only">Filter Dropdown</span><div class="toolbar-button flex items-center cursor-pointer select-none toolbar-button px-2"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" width="24" height="24" class="inline-block" role="presentation"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M3 4a1 1 0 011-1h16a1 1 0 011 1v2.586a1 1 0 01-.293.707l-6.414 6.414a1 1 0 00-.293.707V17l-4 4v-6.586a1 1 0 00-.293-.707L3.293 7.293A1 1 0 013 6.586V4z"></path></svg>&lt;!&ndash;&ndash;&gt;<svg class="flex-shrink-0 ml-2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="6" viewBox="0 0 10 6"><path class="fill-current" d="M8.292893.292893c.390525-.390524 1.023689-.390524 1.414214 0 .390524.390525.390524 1.023689 0 1.414214l-4 4c-.390525.390524-1.023689.390524-1.414214 0l-4-4c-.390524-.390525-.390524-1.023689 0-1.414214.390525-.390524 1.023689-.390524 1.414214 0L5 3.585786 8.292893.292893z"></path></svg></div></button></div>&lt;!&ndash;&ndash;&gt;</div>
       -->         </div>
            </div>
            <LoadingView :loading="loading">
                <table class="w-full divide-y divide-gray-100 dark:divide-gray-700"
                       data-testid="resource-table">
                    <thead class="bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-800">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="td-fit uppercase text-xxs text-gray-500 tracking-wide pl-5 pr-2 py-2"><span class="sr-only">Selected Resources</span></th>
                        <th class="text-left px-2 whitespace-nowrap uppercase text-gray-500 text-xxs tracking-wide py-2">ID</th>
                        <th class="text-left px-2 whitespace-nowrap uppercase text-gray-500 text-xxs tracking-wide py-2">Headline</th>
                        <th class="text-left px-2 whitespace-nowrap uppercase text-gray-500 text-xxs tracking-wide py-2">Start Date</th>
                        <th class="text-left px-2 whitespace-nowrap uppercase text-gray-500 text-xxs tracking-wide py-2">End Date</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody v-if="items.data && items.data.length > 0" class="divide-y divide-gray-100 dark:divide-gray-700">
                    <tr class="group" v-for="(item, index) in items.data" :key="index">
                        <td class="py-2 cursor-pointer td-fit pl-5 pr-5 dark:bg-gray-800 group-hover:bg-gray-50 dark:group-hover:bg-gray-900"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" aria-label="Select Resource 1" data-testid="adverts-items-0-checkbox" dusk="1-checkbox"></td>
                        <td class="px-2 py-2 whitespace-nowrap cursor-pointer dark:bg-gray-800 group-hover:bg-gray-50 dark:group-hover:bg-gray-900">
                            <div class="text-left"> <span class="whitespace-nowrap">{{ item.id }}</span></div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-2 py-2 whitespace-nowrap cursor-pointer dark:bg-gray-800 group-hover:bg-gray-50 dark:group-hover:bg-gray-900">{{ item.headline }}</td>
                        <td class="px-2 py-2 whitespace-nowrap cursor-pointer dark:bg-gray-800 group-hover:bg-gray-50 dark:group-hover:bg-gray-900">{{ item.start_date }}</td>
                        <td class="px-2 py-2 whitespace-nowrap cursor-pointer dark:bg-gray-800 group-hover:bg-gray-50 dark:group-hover:bg-gray-900">{{ item.end_date }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="border-t border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700">
                    <ROPagination  :data="items"  @pagination-change-page="getAdverts" />
                </div>
            </LoadingView>
        </Card>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

//import { TailwindPagination } from 'laravel-vue-pagination';
import ROPagination from "../components/ROPagination.vue";


export default {
    name: "Manager",
    components: {
        ROPagination
    },

    props: {
        shouldShowCheckBoxes: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true,
        },
        currentPageCount: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        allMatchingResourceCount: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        shouldShowActionSelector : {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true,
        }

    },

    data() {
        return {
            items: {},
            loading:false,
            createButtonLabel: 'Create New Advert',
            searchPlaceholder: 'Search Adverts',
            singularName: 'Advert',
            resourceName: 'Adverts',
            itemsPerPage: 10 // Add this line to define the itemsPerPage property

        };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getAdverts();
    },
    methods: {
        getAdverts(page = 1, perPage ) {
            this.loading = true;
            Nova.request().get('/nova-vendor/manager/index?page='+ page + '&perPage=' + perPage)
                .then(response => {
                    this.items = response.data;
                    this.loading = false;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        },

        onItemsPerPageChange() {
            // Call the getAdverts method with the updated itemsPerPage value
            this.getAdverts(1, this.itemsPerPage);
        },
        computed: {
            /**
             * Return the heading for the view
             */
            headingTitle() {
                return 'Adverts'
            },
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style>
/* Your custom styles here */

</style>
```

And here is my ROPagination component

```
    <RenderlessPagination
        :data="data"
        :limit="limit"
        :keep-length="keepLength"
        @pagination-change-page="onPaginationChangePage"
    >
        <template #default="slotProps">
            <div class="rounded-b-lg">
                <nav class="flex justify-between items-center"
                    v-bind="$attrs"
                    aria-label="Pagination"
                    v-if="slotProps.computed.total > slotProps.computed.perPage"
                >
                    <button
                        :class="{
                          'text-xs font-bold py-3 px-4 focus:outline-none rounded-bl-lg focus:ring focus:ring-inset text-primary-500 hover:text-primary-400 active:text-primary-600': slotProps.computed.prevPageUrl,
                          'text-xs font-bold py-3 px-4 focus:outline-none rounded-bl-lg focus:ring focus:ring-inset text-gray-300 dark:text-gray-600': !slotProps.computed.prevPageUrl
                        }"
                            :disabled="!slotProps.computed.prevPageUrl"
                            v-on="slotProps.prevButtonEvents"
                    >
                        <slot name="prev-nav">
                            Previous
                        </slot>
                    </button>
                    <span class="text-xs px-4">
                        {{ currentPageRange(slotProps.computed) }}
                    </span>
                    <button
                        :class="{
                          'text-xs font-bold py-3 px-4 focus:outline-none rounded-br-lg focus:ring focus:ring-inset text-primary-500 hover:text-primary-400 active:text-primary-600': slotProps.computed.nextPageUrl,
                          'text-xs font-bold py-3 px-4 focus:outline-none rounded-bl-lg focus:ring focus:ring-inset text-gray-300 dark:text-gray-600': !slotProps.computed.nextPageUrl
                        }"
                        :disabled="!slotProps.computed.nextPageUrl"
                        v-on="slotProps.nextButtonEvents"
                    >
                        <slot name="next-nav">
                            Next
                        </slot>
                    </button>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </template>
    </RenderlessPagination>
</template>

<script>
import RenderlessPagination from 'laravel-vue-pagination/src/RenderlessPagination.vue';

export default {
    inheritAttrs: false,

    emits: ['pagination-change-page'],

    components: {
        RenderlessPagination,
    },

    props: {
        data: {
            type: Object,
            default: () => ({}),
        },
        limit: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0,
        },
        keepLength: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
    },

    methods: {
        onPaginationChangePage(page) {
            this.$emit('pagination-change-page', page);
        },
        currentPageRange(computed) {
            const currentPage = computed.currentPage;
            const perPage = computed.perPage;
            const total = computed.total;

            if (total === 0) {
                return '';
            }

            const start = (currentPage - 1) * perPage + 1;
            const end = Math.min(currentPage * perPage, total);

            return `${start}-${end} of ${total}`;
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

And here is my Laravel controller

```
namespace Atz\Manager\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Tenant\Advert;

class ManagerController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Get initial advert data for the manager tool.
     *
     * @return
     */
    public function index(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        $perPage = $request->input('perPage', 10);
        $adverts = Advert::paginate($perPage);

        return response()->json($adverts);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller looks right to me, are you sure you are passing the GET params in the Nova request correctly in the "getAdverts" method? Simply "hardcoding" the URL in the get() function might prove to result in some errors.

I am unfamiliar with Nova requests but for [axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro), which works similarly, you pass the route get parameters as the second argument in the get() function.

i.e `axios.get('your/url/here, { 'perPage': variable })`.

You could try adding `dd($request->all()` in the controller to see if the GET parameter 'perPage' is passed to the controller at all.

Comment: I am able to get it working with the dropdown changing the number per page but this does no pass through to the next and previous links so when i go to the next page it reverts back to 10.

Comment: I see. Maybe try adding an early return statement in getAdverts() method and console log perPage to see what is passed when you try to load next page?